# Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:3) of '_GrowableList'

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter and i want to do pagination. I am using one package which name is pull to refresh. All work are doing well but when I reach last data of list then current page is increment with +1 and api call of page=2. in my code its open new page, i want to append with current listview. When i write code for append its throw error "Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:3) of '_GrowableList'."(my english is not good but I hope you are understood).
Following are my code.

```
 int currentPage = 1;
 bool isRefersh = false;

Future<UserPost> getUserPost() async {

    var url =
        "https://myApiLink/getUserPost.php?page=$currentPage";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    var _apiData = UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);

  

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      if(isRefersh == true){
        setState((){
          isRefersh = false;
        });
        refreshController.refreshCompleted();
        return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
      }
      else{
        print(_apiData.hasNextPage.toString());
        if(_apiData.hasNextPage == 0){
          refreshController.loadNoData();
        }else{
          refreshController.loadComplete();
        }
        return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
      }

    } else {
      return UserPost.fromJson(jsondata);
    }
  }
```

My list view code:

```
 FutureBuilder<UserPost>(
                              future: getUserPost(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                  return SmartRefresher(
                                    controller: refreshController,
                                    enablePullUp: true,
    
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                      //close keyboard while scroll
                                        keyboardDismissBehavior:
                                        ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
                                        //itemCount: isFilter? ComparisonText.length : snapshot.data!.data!.length,
                                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.data!.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    
                                          var postList = snapshot.data!.data![i];
                                          String tempSearch =
                                          postList.azakhanaName.toString();
)}
```

onRefersh for refreshing and onLoading for pagination.

```
onRefresh: () async{
                                  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                                  setState(() {
                                    isRefersh = true;
                                    currentPage = 1;
                                  });
                                },

                                onLoading: () async {
                                  if(snapshot.data!.hasNextPage == 0){
                                    refreshController.loadNoData();
                                  }else{
                                    setState(() {
                                      currentPage++;
                                      snapshot.data!.data!.addAll(snapshot.data!.data!);
                                    });
                                    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                                    refreshController.loadComplete();
                                  }

                                },
```

I am trying to append listview with new data like this and and error also throw in this code:

```
snapshot.data!.data!.addAll(snapshot.data!.data!);
```

Comment: What do you expect adding all elements of a `List` to *itself* to do?  That's what you're doing with `snapshot.data!.data!.addAll(snapshot.data!.data!)`.  If want to duplicate all of the elements, then you'd need to iterate over a *copy* of the `List` so that you aren't modifying the same `List` you're reading from: `snapshot.data!.data!.addAll(snapshot.data!.data!.toList())`.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
Actually I want to append new data in a list. when i open app api call with page=1 and data limit is 5, so when i reach data of 5 new api will call with page=2 and append data to current listview.(Basically i want to do pagination)